# Workflow of sales modules in odoo10

Tags: odoo-10

I want workflow of sales in odoo10.When I search, like setting>workflows>workflows, there is no data in it.How can I get  the workflow of the module.

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: I need workflow  of the sales  module  in odoo10. Where am i suppose to  look for  the  workflow  of existing module in odoo10.

Comment: Inside Odoo V10 there is no any workflow inside Sales. If you want to see the all workflows then activate developer mode and go to Settings => Technical => Workflows => Workflows.

Comment: There is no workflow in odoo10, see http://bloopark.de/en_US/blog/the-bloopark-times-english-2/post/odoo-10-workflows-partial-removal-265